# Why query that returns edges in neo4j does not work when using neo4j and sigma.js?

Tags: javascript, neo4j, sigma.js

When I run a query such as this:

```
Match (n:System) where n.Name = 'James' Return n
```

Sigma/neo4j js libraries do not display the relationships between the nodes returned, however neo4j does. Anyone got any ideas how I could alter the query to return the edges.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you have "Connect Result Nodes" checked in the Settings section of the Neo4j browser, which issues an additional query after your Cypher query to find all the relationships between the nodes that were returned.

You would need your query to return either relationships in addition to nodes or paths, which include both.

Alternately, if you have a query for nodes, if you can collect those nodes you can use [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) `apoc.algo.cover()` to get all the relationships between the nodes in the collection.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. What do you mean by collect all nodes? Is this as simple as put all the node idsin a list?

Comment: This is referring to using the [collect()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) function to collect your nodes into a list. The `apoc.algo.cover()` call expects a list of nodes as input, and will provide relationships between them as output.

Comment: Thanks InversFalcon, I tried using it and I get the error msessage that apoc.algo.cover() is not a function on my database, I have been trying to add it and it haven't figured out how. Is the fact I am using a community edition of neo4j mean that I cannot configure new plugins?

Comment: It's a procedure, not a function, so you'll need to CALL it and YIELD the `rel` variable